# Putting faces navigation rules in a separate file

Tags: jsf-2

I have read somewhere that faces navigation rules may be placed in a separate xml file from faces-config.xml but I can't find that reference anywhere now. Has anyone come across this? JSF 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `context-param` in web.xml file of the application. Just that with the files you want for JSF.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml, /WEB-INF/faces-managed-beans.xml, /WEB-INF/faces-navigation.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: A simple tutorial here 
http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-split-faces-config-xml-into-multiple-files/